# Getting the right numeric data type cast for a specific ASBD buffer

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audio-recording, audiounit

I've got an `AudioBuffer` with its `void *mData` full of freshly-rendered audio samples using Apple's CoreAudio Audio Unit API, but I have a problem getting the samples in the right format. The ASBD of said buffer is as follows:

```
Float64 mSampleRate        44100
UInt32  mFormatID          1819304813
UInt32  mFormatFlags       41
UInt32  mBytesPerPacket    4
UInt32  mFramesPerPacket   1
UInt32  mBytesPerFrame     4
UInt32  mChannelsPerFrame  2
UInt32  mBitsPerChannel    32
UInt32  mReserved          0
```

I got this by debugging the application and executing an `AudioUnitGetProperty(rioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, ...)` call. The `mFormatFlags` field implies the following flags (I don't know of any formal decode method, I just got it by trying out different combinations of `kAudioUnitFlags` until I got `41`):

```
kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked | kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat
```

Which type of data should I cast the buffer with? I've already tried with `Float32`, `SInt32`, but they're not it.

I intend to do a conversion to `SInt16` afterwards, but I can't do it if I don't get the right format for the samples first.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, iOS will not deliver floating point data to you directly. Instead you should ask for `SInt16` (and thus, set `mBitsPerChannel` to 16 as well) and then manually convert the integer data to floats by dividing each number by 32767.

Answer (score 1):

Based on that ASBD, the data is stereo non-interleaved 32 bit floats, which is the canonical format for Audio Units on Mac OS X.

You should be able to cast the `mData` field to a `float *` and get one channel of audio data.  The full stereo audio should be contained in an `AudioBufferList` with two buffers each containing one channel.

Why did casting to `Float32` not work?

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```
   - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
   fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection

       //calback function

        const AudioStreamBasicDescription *audioDescription = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer));

        int sampleRate        = (int)audioDescription ->mSampleRate;
        int channelsPerFrame  = (int)audioDescription ->mChannelsPerFrame;
        UInt32 formatFlag     =  audioDescription ->mFormatFlags;

        if (formatFlag & kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat) {
          NSLog(@"IS FLOAT");

        } else if ( formatFlag & kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger) {
          NSLog(@"IS Signed Integer");
        }
```

}